# How to access appdata folder and print file without knowing username?

Tags: python

This is the code.

```
from sys import argv
import os

local = os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA')

f = open(local + '\\GeometryDash\\CCGameManager.dat')
    file_contents = f.read()
    print (file_contents)
f.close()

f = open(local + '\\GeometryDash\\CCGameManager2.dat')
    file_contents = f.read()
    print (file_contents)
f.close()
```

How do I access 'appdata\local\GeometryDash\CCGameManager.dat' and 'appdata\local\GeometryDash\CCGameManager2.dat' then print them.

Comment: Please elaborate on what errors you are getting when you attempt to run the above code and add any tracebacks if you have any.

Comment: Only thing we can say right now, is that no line of the code you show should be indented.

Comment: console just opens and closes

Comment: Your issue that that probably that your program in opening and running, finishing and then subsequently closing. Put a time.sleep(20) at the end of the program, and your program should remain open long enough for you to read what is going on. I suggest you use an ide to run your code. Start with IDLE. This way you can see what your program is outputting without it closing on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using "%appdata%" instead of os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") would work.